# Configure Splunk in Springboot and Docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, logging, splunk

I am a bit confused on the solutions found online. I need to send the application logs already written to a file to a Splunk server hosted in my organisation. How do I do it?

From what I learnt so far - I can use the **Splunk Universal Forwarder** to achieve this. Would it be correct to run a Splunk universal forwarder Docker instance pointing to Splunk hosted server? Please confirm. If yes, how do I pass the host/port to the container? Is it passed using the below env param?

- *SPLUNK_STANDALONE_URL*=http://splunk.host.com:9100

These are just my observations and assumptions. Please correct me if I am wrong OR please suggest if there is a better way to achieve this.

All the examples suggest to run a Splunk and a universal forwarder containers. Nowhere I could find an example on how to connect to an external Splunk server. Hence any examples, snippets would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

First, the Splunk [Universal Forwarder](https://docs.splunk.com/Splexicon:Universalforwarder) is a stand-alone application that's entire job is to send data to Splunk Enterprise (or Cloud).

There is no need to complicate installing a simple, lightweight utility by embedding it in a Docker container - unless, and only unless, you need to have the UF *inside* a container to read logs therein.

What steps from the [UF install guide](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Forwarder/latest/Forwarder/Installanixuniversalforwarder) have you followed?

You say you are "*a bit confused on the solutions found online*". What has you confused? What "solutions" have you found online?

Comment: I got confused whether to go with UF or SpringIntegration. If I have to use SI, I'll have to configure the adapter and then manually create & send the events to the Splunk Enterprise that would be an overhead to the developers, I feel. So thought UF would be a better option.

Comment: This is for the microservices project that uses SpringBoot and Docker. Hence thought of running a UF in Docker container that would read the log and forward it to the Splunk Enterprise hosted on-prem. That said, I'd like to know if aforementioned ENV argument can be used to pass the host and port. I haven't worked on Splunk.  Please share your thoughts.

Comment: @continuousLearner - this is *likely* going to be a better fit for using the [HTTP Event Collector (HEC)](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Data/UsetheHTTPEventCollector)

Comment: Sure, I'll explore HEC and come back. Thanks